# Filtering a 2 column list using command line

Tags: regex, sorting, terminal, line, uniq

I have a file separated into two columns; ips and hostnames.

**Ex**

```
xx.xx.xx.1    name.com
xx.xx.xx.2    name.com
xx.xx.xx.3    unique.name.com
xx.xx.xx.4    name.com
xx.xx.xx.5    more.unique.com
xx.xx.xx.6    name.com
.
.
.
.
```

I would like to remove the lines with the repeated 'name.com'. I tried a few uniq and sort commands but couldn't figure it out. Help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
perl -ane '$seen{$F[1]}++ or print' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Once a problem gets this complex I tend to fall back on Perl:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

%count = ();
while (<>) {
    my ($ip, $hostname) = split /\s+/;
    print $_ if ($hostname eq 'name.com' and ++$count{$hostname} == 1);
}
```